# `': No such file or directoryute 'sh` when starting docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I have a proxy container, which has an entrypoint script to create a self-signed certificate on startup if none is found - if not, the pod crashes on startup in kubernetes, so I cannot copy the real certificate in

So my question is two-fold;

**1- There has GOT to be a better way to do that**

**2- If not, what on earth does `': No such file or directoryute 'sh` mean - that is the only thing in the container logs.**

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1-alpine

RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/cache/nginx
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/log/nginx
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d
RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/run/nginx.pid

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /custom-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /custom-entrypoint.sh

USER nginx

COPY service.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/service.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY .keep *.include /etc/nginx/includes/

COPY 50x.html /usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html

COPY ./ssl/* /etc/nginx/cert/

ENTRYPOINT ["/custom-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And the entrypoint script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -e

if [ -f "/etc/nginx/cert/listener.key" ]; then
    # Create a certificate if none exists - to prevent a crash
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
    -subj "/C=CA/ST=QC/O=Company, Inc./CN=example.com" \
    -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com" \
    -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -keyout /etc/nginx/cert/listener.key \
    -out /etc/nginx/cert/listener.crt;
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: Perhaps unrelated but the container now tags itself as proxy_1ner instead of the usual proxy_1 ...

Comment: Can you put the (signed) certificate and private key in a Kubernetes Secret, and mount that in your Deployment spec?  Then the certificate file would always be present.  You also might double-check whether your entrypoint script has Unix line endings, if you do development on a Windows system, since I think that could lead to that mangled error.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue just now. Found that my entry point `run.sh` had CRLF (Windows) instead of just LF (Linux) line ends. Re-saved as LF, rebuild image, and it run as expected.

Comment: Yup! Never would have thought about CRLF. Thanks